# Trying to insert UNIQUE values using PHP and mySQL into database if certain values do not already exist

Tags: php, mysql, duplicates

Currently Ive been just making a SQL column UNIQUE to block duplicate entries but now I need to allow duplicate entries if another column is different. I am not sure on the best way to do this. Essentially I would like to do something as follows but it just inserts the same values multiple times.

```
// $link  is being outputted from a external RSS feed //
// $name and $location are account holder names //

$name = 'Bob';

$sql = "SELECT link FROM `table` WHERE name='$name'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $db_link = $row['link'];

        if($link == $db_link){
            // Pass and do nothing
        }else{
            // Insert into database if 3 values do not exist already
            $sql2 = "INSERT INTO `table` (link, name) VALUES ('$link','$name')";

            if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql2)) {
                echo "record created successfully";
            } else {
                //echo "Error: " . $sql2 . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So basically I am trying to avoid showing duplicates per account holder, but a different account holder can have the same link in the database. Sorry if this is confusing..
If the name is different then allow a link to be a duplicate.
 I have looked at similar questions asked but do not understand the methods explained and if they would be the right solution I am looking for.  Thanks!

Comment: you can index more than one column at a time `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_name ON table_name ( column1, column2,...);`

Comment: If I were to make name and location UNIQUE with link wouldn't that only allow one name and location to be inserted? Maybe I am confused on how that would work

Comment: No, it makes each combination of name and location unique, not each column by itself.

Comment: That's the difference between a single-column index and a multi-column index.

Comment: Ah really Thank you, so I need to understand this better. If I create a UNIQUE index for 'link' and 'name' in the database it will require the two columns to be UNIQUE together not just one or the other?

Comment: Your loop is not checking whether the link appears in any of the rows returned by the query. It's checking each row, and if it contains a different link it adds the link, even though some other row could contain the link.

Comment: Yes you are correct, I am researching how to create a multi-column index in an existing table, or could that be done in a query?

Comment: @Barmar I think I was able to do it with ALTER TABLE `table_name` ADD UNIQUE (`link`, `name`);

Comment: That will work. Then you don't need the loop at all, just try to insert and check for an error.

Comment: @Barmar if you could add your comment as an answer I will accept it as the correct answer, it was what I was needing! Thank you

Comment: You mean @tim's comment?

Comment: on it, give me a sec :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want a unique index on multiple columns

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_name ON table_name (link,name);
```

or

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD UNIQUE (link, name);
```

Comment: haha dang I was thinking Barmar gave that comment, my bad.. Thanks Tim!